# Keyboard modifier to use <CAPS> with xmodmap

Tags: keyboard-layout, xmodmap

I've just installed a fresh Ubuntu. For the last 2 years I've used a system that allowed me to use my <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> key as a keyboard modifier to get the character I want.

For isntance, if I wanted the GBP Pound sterling £ symbol I could type

<kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd> + <kbd>l</kbd> and it would output <kbd>£</kbd>

If I wanted a German umlaut (ü ö ä Ä Ü ) I could type

<kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> + <kbd>u</kbd> + <kbd>:</kbd> and it would output <kbd>ü</kbd>

How is this achieved? (I assume something with xmodmap)

Comment: Whi do you need three keys when you can use one or maximum two keys to type those characters if you use German keyboard layout?

Comment: I'd prefer the newer `xkb` over `xmodmap`, but I think dwcoder has the correct answer anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you even need `xmodmap`, you can just set you *Compose Key* to `<CapsLock>`.

This post explains how to do it on some Ubuntu flavours:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ComposeKey

Comment: +1. Also, it's worth mentioning that one can define custom compose keys in `~/.XCompose`.

Answer (score 0):

Open the dash and type "layout", select the item that appears. Look for "Options" and there look for caps lock preference.

If what you try to find is not there, install `dconf-editor` using `sudo apt-get install dconf-editor`, look for the key `org.gnome.desktop.input-sources.xkb-options` or `org.unity.desktop.input-sources.xkb-options` and add `compose:caps` to the options, like this:

[image]

that should do the job.

Resources:

- [The arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GNOME#Modify_Keyboard_with_XkbOptions)
- [xkeyboard-config manpage](http://www.dsm.fordham.edu/cgi-bin/man-cgi.pl?topic=xkeyboard-config&ampsect=7)